# How to extend/customize unittest's shortDescription()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

`unittest.shortDescription()` returns only the first line of the test method's docstring.

Is there a way to change this behavior, e.g. to display the entirety of the docstring, or to display another message ?

Would I need to override `shortDescription()` ?

**EDIT**: I did know that shortDescription() takes no arguments (besides the implicit object reference), but I was very unclear in the wording of my question.  What I'm really looking for is pointers to **how** to override shortDescription() and get at, say, the entire contents of the docstring.  Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Override shortDescription() in your test class as follows:

```python
Class Foo(unittest.TestCase):
      def shortDescription(self):
          doc = self._testMethodDoc
          return doc or None
```

Comment: it's def `shortDescription(self)`

Answer (score 0):

`unittest.shortDescription()` takes no arguments. You would have to override it to get the entire docstring.

Comment: Thanks fiacre.  I was being dumb in the way I worded my question....What I really am looking for is pointers as to how to override shortDescription() so that I can get at and display the full docstring.  Thanks !

Comment: @tmark , Understood.  The only way to accomplish that would to be to subclass unittest.  OTOH, might it be easier to use a mixin that has a decorator?  Just wondering -- I have no code that does either.